# 'list' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I have below code.
I am getting error as `'list' undeclared (first use in this function)`.
Please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct list{
int data;
struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list *head;

int main()
{
    struct list *start;
    int i;

    start = (list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("\nEnter the data : \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    start->data = i;
    start->next = NULL;
    while(list->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to post screenshots...

Comment: @ThiefMaster better than posting nothing (no code, no error log)..

Comment: Comments: 1. don't cast the return value of `malloc()`; 2. don't use `sizeof struct` as its argument  but `sizeof(*start)`; 3. Why `typedef struct list *head` when you never use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the type `list` instead of variable name `start`. Proper code:

```
while (start->next != NULL)
{
    start = start->next;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot... Ya I did a mistake

Answer (score 3):

[Don't cast the return type of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - there's no benefit of it and in this case you did it wrong!

```
start = (list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

should be

```
start = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

the type `list *` doesn't exist; you meant `struct list *`.

You can make it even more safe by writing

```
start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
```

this way you automatically `malloc` enough bytes for the (pointer) type of `start`, which is useful when you later change the type of `start` - the `malloc` call doesn't change a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
start = (list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

includes an unnecessary typecast.  Just do

```
start = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

However, your code has more trouble than this.  I can answer your question best by asking a question of my own:  in your mind, is `list` a type or an object?

If you answer this question, one suspects that you can fix your code.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct list{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

typedef struct list *head;

int main()
{
    struct list *start;
    int i;

    start = (list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("\nEnter the data : \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    start->data = i;
    start->next = NULL;
    while(start->next != NULL)
    {
        start = start->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you can define the type (list *)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is named « start » and you called it « list ».

Answer (score 0):

```
start = (struct list *) malloc ...
```

You've missed **struct** in casting.
Which is not neccessary at all as  Anthales pointed out.

```
start = malloc ...
```

Comment: For gods sake, don't cast the return type of malloc! Stop this C++ madness!

Answer (score 0):

One problem you had is you were re-using struct in declaring your struct pointer after you had created a typedef, `struct list *start;`. Also the struct and typedef cannot have the same name. You get this:

```
cc  -Wall test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:13: error: ‘list_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:13: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:13: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:13: error: ‘start’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:13: error: ‘cur’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:13: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
test.c:16: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

You can choose to use struct list everywhere and skip making using typedef. Use of typedef simplifies how your code reads as noted here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29#typedef

I've rewritten what you have just so I could compile it and understand it a little better, and so I could put some data into one node. I remember the whole struct typedef concept taking a little time to sink in, when I was learning C. So, don't give up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list list_t;

int main()
{
    list_t *start, *cur;
    int i;

    start = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));

    if (NULL != start)
    {
        cur = start; /* Preserve list head, and assign to cur for list trarversal. */
        printf("\nEnter the data : ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        cur->data = i;
        cur->next = NULL;
        cur = start;
        while(cur != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", cur->data);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Malloc failed. Program ending.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```